# A better closed-form solution to recursive equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

Is there a way to represent 
\begin{equation}
 M(n)=-2\times |M(n-1)-0.5|+1
\end{equation}

in closed-form without using the $min$ function? i.e. not:

\begin{equation}
 M(n)=2\times\min{\big\{2^{n-1}M(1)-\lfloor2^{n-1}M(1)\rfloor,\lfloor2^{n-1}M(1)+1\rfloor-2^{n-1}M(1)\big\}}
\end{equation}

where $ 0 \leq M(1)\leq 1$

Comment: Is $M$ a function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @DanielV M is any real number from 0 to 1